# Clearing Magento Special Price Date Fields Programmatically

Tags: php, magento, soap

I'm working on a customization to the Magento SOAP V2 API for product updates.  We use a 3rd party integration and it is limited in its capabilities.  One thing it can't do is clear the date fields for special_price_from and special_price_to dates on an item.  A work around I came up with is to set the dates to some placeholder that I catch in an API extension and overwrite the value to clear it.  I'm able to catch the value and change the product data in the API update before the product gets changed, but if I simply set the value to an empty string it throws an error saying "No date part found in ''".  I tried null, but that just skipped the value, and "0" did strange things.  Does anyone know what you can set the date to so that when saved it clears the field?  I'm working on trying to figure out how the UI handles it in the Admin but I haven't figured it out yet and thought I'd get the question out there sooner rather than later.

UPDATE:
It appears this isn't working for clearing the date in the Admin UI either.  I could have sworn it was but now it isn't.  I have read that hacking the Zend library and changing the regular expression by removing the "/u" switch at the end fixes this.  Is that the "fix" or just a band-aid?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I had a conflict with another extension that was throwing an exception when trying to create a Zend_Date object using the value I had just tried to change it to.  I disabled that extension and I'm now able to edit the special price to/from dates both in the admin UI and from my API extension.

Comment: What extension were you using.  I'm having the same problem clearing the dates.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's been so long I can't recall at this point.  I think it was something I had written and not a commercially available one, but I can't be sure.